# Its not outputting text after nesting it inside another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I got a silly error that I don't know why is happening.

Basically i get the return from the AJAX  code "The table PAGES exists" and I can output that to the `<p>` tag if I put it after declaring `var response = data;` but somehow it won't output anything when is inside the IF statement inside the `functionResponse`.

Can anyone tell me why? Am I passing the variable wrong?

```
   $(document).ready(function(){


        function functionResponse (response){

            if (response == "The table PAGES exists"){
                $("p").html(response);



            } 
            } // close of functionResponse      

$("#iForm").submit( function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var user = $("input[name=username]").val();
    var password = $("input[name=password]").val();
    var dbName = $("input[name=dbName]").val();
    var server = $("input[name=server]").val(); 


        $.get("1.php", {username: user, password: password, dbName: dbName, server: server },function(data){

            var response = data;            



            functionResponse (response);

                        }) // close of .get


    })

})
```

Comment: When comparing strings it might be a good idea to trim the comparison, you might think it just says "The table PAGES exists" but really it might have some spaces, tabs or breaks before and after that string.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But it works if i put it somewhere else in the code. so its just a problem of not working inside the other function for some reason

Comment: You could/should also assess your `if` condition: `console.log(response == "The table PAGES exists")`. Then you'll know what's going wrong.

Comment: does the assignment of the <p> html work outside that if block?

Comment: oh, and move your response function outside the ready function. you might have some scope problem there that the get response can't access that function.

Comment: @invertedSpear It does work outside the functionResponse. I added $.trim(response) inside the if statement and somehow now it works. Its weird that i has to be trimmed inside another function but it doesnt need trim if i make the same if statement without the function. Thank you! :)

Comment: I agree with David. First log your ajax response to make sure your string matches. Strings are very tricky since they are case sensitive and whitespace at the end matters. Make sure to trim for best results

Comment: @JonathanThurft: For my amusement, can you also try `if(response+"" == "The table PAGES exists")`?

Comment: @Grinn that doesnt work this is the only thing that works `if ($.trim(response) == "The table PAGES exists")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since trimming worked at my suggestion I'm entering it as an answer with the following explanation.

the return handler for your get function was able to assign the value to the p tag because assigning doesn't care about white space, especially assigning html, the browser just ignores all that extra blank space.

It's not passing it to a function that made it break, it was the string comparison. The browser may not care about white space in the HTML, but JavaScript cares a whole lot about white space when doing a string comparison.

The text

```
"This is some text"
```

and

```
"    This is some text    "
```

will appear the same when the browser renders them, as repeated spaces are ignored. But just by looking at them you can see that they are not the same string. Javascript will not ignore the white space that leads and trails your sting unless you tell it to by trimming it.

Answer (score -1):

initializing a variable with "var" only makes it readable in that scope so your trying to call it another scope down either move the vars outside of submit or take out "var" which makes them global.

Comment: he is passing it to the function, and defining response as the passed value, what he's doing is fine there.

Comment: document.ready doesnt have a closing bracket. what does the console say